# RSpec error: test couldn't find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd, rspec-rails

I am trying to test this part of controller with Rspec:

```
@supercar = Supercar.find(params[:id])
```

Here is my controller spec to test the part mentioned above:

```
before (:each) do
  @supercar = Factory :supercar
end

describe "show" do

  it "assigns the requested supercar to the @supercar" do
    get :show, :id => @supercar.id
    assigns(:supercar).should == @supercar
  end
...
```

However, I've tried to run command `rake db:migrate`, but still getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: @supercar = Factory :supercar
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'supercar'
```

Comment: I'm surprised it's not looking for table 'supercars'.  Have you set the table name on your Supercar Model?

Comment: Shouldn't the factory call look like `Factory.create(:supercar)` - This looks like old FactoryGirl syntax.  I'm used to seeing something more like `@car = FactoryGirl.create(:supercar)`

Comment: Make sure you have properly setup your test database:run rake db:test:clone after rake db:migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to run this command:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

It is preparing the test database, by loading the scheme there.